# iphone google maps get latitude and longitude of an address

Tags: iphone, mapkit, google-maps

Is there any URL from google maps, that returns me the latitude and longitude of an address.
i want to use these lat and long details in iPhone Map kit to plot some information.

Answer (score 5):

This is working for me:

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%@&output=csv", 
                      [addressField.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSString *locationString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
```

good luck

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a built in way to do reverse reverse geocoding, but I'm new to the iPhone, Objective C, Cocoa and XCode, so.

This is the best [article](http://webhole.net/2010/03/10/turnaddress-to-latitude-and-longitude/) I could find on the subject.

Goes in my 'could be good' bookmark drawer :)

The second example URL gives an XML file that you could fetch with `initWithContentsOfURL`, and then `getObjectForKey:@"lat"` and `getObjectForKey:@"lng"` or something along those lines.